# Sending emails from multiple Email Send Definitions to specific records in a single Data Extension

Tags: api, marketing-cloud

Is is possible to have multiple Email Send Definitions send email to specific records/rows in a single Data Extension. If yes, how do you specify the data extension records that you want to send the email to?

Example: 
   Data Extension has 30 records
   Email Send Definition1 sends email to DE records 1-10
   Email Send Definition2 sends email to DE records 11-20
   Email Send Definition3 sends email to DE records 21-30

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Data Filter that targets the Data Extension. Email Send Definitions can send directly to a Data Filter. At time of send a temporary DE is created based on the DF, the temp DE is sent to, and the temp DE is then deleted.

However, if you want to filter just based on row number, that will have to be included manually. Data Extension rows do not have an intrinsic row number or modify/create date.

Comment: This is my point - a data filter creates a data extension that you can send to, but you wouldn't be able to send to individual rows directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This helps a lot! :) I will definitely need to create a data filter based on specific criteria, I only used specific row numbers in the question as an example.

Answer (score 0):

No,  this isn't directly possible.  You need to send to an entire data extension.